# Редактирование DataFrame в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Я использую библиотеку Pandas.
У меня имеется DataFrame - `data`:

```
   Age  Sex     Name 
0  28   male    Kirill
1  32   female  Alina
2  12   female  Sasha
```

Я хочу заменить строковой столбец `Sex` на числа, то есть вместо `male` поставить `1`, а вместо `female` - `0`

Я пытаюсь сделать это в цикле

```
for i in range(data.Age.size()):
    if data.Sex[i]=='male'
        data.Sex[i]=1
    else:
        data.Sex[i]=0
```

Но  я получаю `SettingWithCopyWarning`.
Как правильно заменить столбец на числовые дынные?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Pandas: Replacing column values in dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23307301/4279)

Answer (score 8):

```
data = data.replace(to_replace=['male', 'female'], value=[1, 0])
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Ответ работает в данном случае, не нужно его минусовать. В общем случае замену одной колонкой лучше ограничить: `data.Sex.replace(.., inplace=True)` или `df.Sex = df.Sex.map(dict(female=0, male=1))`

Comment: Можно еще добавить приведение форматов, для облегчения последующих вычислений: `data = data.replace(to_replace=['male', 'female'], value=[1, 0]).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 2):

Еще можно так (более сложный вариант):

```
data['Sex'] = data['Sex'].map(lambda x: 1 if x=='male' else 0)
```